# Is there a way to move multiple selected files in powershell via $variable

Tags: powershell

I was looking for way to move multiple files from one directory into the other using powershell variables.

Lets say I have var `$domain = test.test` and I have four files in directory `$domain.csr $domain.crt $domain.pfx $domain.key"`. I can't seem to be able to do it this way `Move-Items "$domain.csr $domain.crt $domain.pfx $domain.key" ../certs`
Is there a one line comand to perform that?

Thanks.

Comment: that list is a _single string_ ... the `Remove-Item` cmdlet requires ONE string for each source. you can have an array of strings, but your sample is one long string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to pass the source path as a `<String[]>`, so try:

```
Move-Item -Path $domain.csr, $domain.crt, $domain.pfx, $domain.key -Destination ../certs
```

Comment: Yep, the commas make it an array.  You don't even need the double-quotes.

Comment: And you do not even need `-path`.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is not difficult:
Just try

```
Move-item $domain\*  ../certs
```